# Passing a function to a module without specifying its arguments

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to write a

```
 Module Arg[f_,n_]
```

that takes a function f (having <=n arguments) and a natural number n and outputs the n-th argument of the function f.

As an example, suppose that f is defined by

```
f[a_,b_]=a^2+b^2.
```

Then,

```
Arg[f[s,t],1]
```

should be s;

while

```
Arg[f[u,v],2]
```

should be v.

My question is whether this is possible. If so, what should I write in the place of "???" below?

```
Arg[f_,n_] := Module[{}, ??? ]
```

Note that I don't want to specify a_ and b_ in the definition of Arg like

```
 Arg[f_,a_,b_,n_]
```

EDIT: "Arg" is just my name for the module not the internal function Arg of Mathematica.

Comment: You realize `Arg` is an internal function, right? Did you mean to rewrite `Arg` (doesn't look like it from the definition) or was it just a poor choice of function name? Also, you probably meant `Arg[f[u,v],2]` gives `v`?

Comment: You just bungled up my edits @bel :)

Comment: @yoda Sorry :(. I'm having some trouble with JS on my browser. perhaps that is why I did not receive the "previous edit" notice. Feel free to rollback my changes or merge them with yours.

Comment: @belisarius Nah, no worries :)

Comment: Thank you for the edits and the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps

```
SetAttributes[arg, HoldFirst];
arg[f_[x___], n_] := {x}[[n]]

f[a_, b_] := a^2 + b^2.
arg[f[arg[f[s, t], 1], t], 1]
arg[f[s, t], 2]

(*
 -> s
 -> t
*)

arg[ArcTan[f[Cos@Sin@x, x], t], 1]

(*
->  x^2. + Cos[Sin[x]]^2
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your second example should give `u`, this should do the job:

```
ClearAll[arg];
SetAttributes[arg, HoldFirst];
arg[g_, n_] := Module[
  {tmp, ret},
  Unprotect[Part];
  tmp = Attributes[Part];
  SetAttributes[Part, HoldFirst];
  ret = Part[g, n];
  ClearAttributes[Part, HoldFirst];
  SetAttributes[Part, tmp];
  Protect[Part];
  ret
  ]
```

so that

```
f[a_, b_] = a^2 + b^2.;
arg[f[s, t], 1]
```

gives `s`.

This is very heavy-handed though, so I expect someone will find something better soon enough.

This is a bit better (doesn't redefine built-in functions even temporarily):

```
ClearAll[arg2];
SetAttributes[arg2, HoldFirst];
arg2[g_, n_] := Hold[g][[1, n]]
```